# What do you call a question when the answer is in said question?

Tags: single-word-requests, questions

For example: "What religion are Buddhist Monks?" 
Obviously the answer is Buddhism, and the answer is in the question. 
What is this technique called?

Comment: Be careful.  Here are three examples:  Who's buried at Grant's Tomb?  Answer:  No one, it's an above-ground mausoleum, not a grave site.  How long do Macy's one-day sales last?  Answer: Two days.  The official day of the sale, and the day before is a "preview day," but the same prices apply.  What time does the 6 o'clock news start on Channel 4 in New York?  Answer: Check your clock if you're tuned in; it actually starts at 5:58, consistently.

Comment: Steven Littman's examples would be called _trick questions_.

Comment: Avoid posting questions that do not detail the effort you have already made to find an answer, solutions you have already rejected, and why. Such questions may be closed as lacking research effort until they are edited to include research. Research can take many forms: checking references such as an online English dictionary, thesaurus, or grammar, searching this site for similar questions, searching the web, or putting substantial thought into the question on your own. See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Comment: Buddhism is not a religion, so I dunno. Third base.

Answer (score 5):

**"tautological question"**

Quoting [Confucius: A Guide for the Perplexed By Yong Huang](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1R9MAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%22tautological%20question%22&source=bl&ots=xlMgpv2rzY&sig=P4gfitxJYRcYbcKmZD-P2WPKSmA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjul6-v4MDKAhVJWhQKHbWmDkIQ6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q=%22tautological%20question%22&f=false)

> In other words, for Toulmin, the question “why should I be moral,”
>   just like the question “why are all scarlet things red,” is a
>   [tautological](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tautology) question. To answer this question, we can only ask a
>   rhetorical question, “What else can scarlet things be?'

Comment: One day a student interrupted Confucius at a meal.  "Please, Master," said the student.  "Can you tell me the sound of one hand clapping?"  Confucius backhanded the student across the face, saying, "Kinda like that.  Now get outta here and let me finish my lunch."  Some nuance may have been lost in translation.

Comment: 'What do you call' asks for more than a way to describe the item. 'A leaky radiator' would be how some people describe one problem sometimes encountered, but, like the above, has not even strong collocational status. And, like the above, it would not  /does not merit an answer on ELU. The answer is unhelpful, as some might even consider 'tautological question' a compound, like 'rhetorical question'. There are few Google hits for the string _tautological question_, so this is not 'what you would call' it. Just how some might describe it. As evidenced by the lack of a citing of the string.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think either the noun *tautology* or adjective *tautological* are helpful to the OP and potentially someone else. I admit as you say *tautological question* is clunky/ugly, but it was best I could come up with !

Comment: But ELU is aimed principally at linguists. 'Tautological' has (ironically) been covered here far too many times. Do we want answers with say 'pink parasol' in response to 'What could we call ...?'

Comment: Ok I admitted my answer was far from my best one ever . However that being said, I don’t think us commenting on this 4 year question will bring the improvements to ELU that I think you want. I suspect such issues needs addressed on ELU Meta and even then it is a very uphill battle. I, for one, normally avoid the debate and politics on ELU meta, though I am pretty sure lots of attempts have been made to improve quality and have failed. BTW I am certainly not a linguist; I am only on this site for a little fun and distraction from real life.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most accurate answer (if perhaps not the most elegant or surprising one) is "**a question that answers itself**", a phrase that [returns about 2,480 Google search results](https://www.google.com/#q=%22a+question+that+answers+itself%22) so seems to be in reasonably accepted use.

This concept has a large overlap with the other proposed answers of a "rhetorical question" and a "tautological question", but a question that answers itself need not be posed for rhetorical effect (in which case it would not be a rhetorical question), and conversely a rhetorical question need not answer itself (e.g. "what is this, some kind of joke?" in response to an absurd request that is however clearly not a joke).

I do agree that the example sentence provided by OP qualifies as a tautological question, and would also qualify as a rhetorical question in most reasonable contexts.

Comment: What religion is the Buddhist Monk who downvoted my answer?

Answer (score -1):

I would call it a self-evident question.